# Haskell: Finding maximum value in a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples

```
[(0,9.1104335791443),(1,11.575836902790225),(2,6.928203230275509),(3,10.816653826391969)]
```

For a list like this one, `[(A,T),(A,T),(A,T),(A,T)]`, Is there a way I can find the maximum value among the Ts while ignoring the As?

Comment: It looks here that since the `T`s have no "argument", there is no "maximum".

Comment: The problem is, at the same time, i'd like to keep the first number as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Use `maximumBy (comparing snd)`, where `maximumBy` is from `Data.List` and `comparing` is from `Data.Ord`.

I'll leave it to you to find out what are these functions. [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) is the place to find out.